# Wrapping Stripe create customer callbacks in Fibers in Meteor

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments

I'm having trouble getting Stripe.js to work when creating a new customer. Here is their Node.js code in their tutorial:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_9999999999999999999999");

// (Assuming you're using express - expressjs.com)
// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
var stripeToken = request.body.stripeToken;

stripe.customers.create({
  source: stripeToken,
  description: 'payinguser@example.com'
}).then(function(customer) {
  return stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
    currency: "usd",
    customer: customer.id
  });
}).then(function(charge) {
  saveStripeCustomerId(user, charge.customer);
});
```

This is my attempt. I wrapped all the callbacks in `Meteor.bindEnvironment` because async callbacks need to run in a fiber. I get an error in the server console:

```
Exception while invoking method 'submitOrder' Error: Stripe: Unknown arguments (function (/* arguments */) {
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for wrapping this in fibers? Or utilizing Meteor.wrapAsync?

```
var createStripeCustomer = function(ShoppingCartObject){
    check(ShoppingCartObject, Object);
    var stripe = Stripe("sk_test_9999999999999999");
    // (Assuming you're using express - expressjs.com)
    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    var stripeToken = ShoppingCartObject.charge.token;

    stripe.customers.create(
        {
          source: stripeToken,
          description: ShoppingCartObject._id,
          email: ShoppingCartObject.customerInfo.agentEmail,
        }, 
        Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(customer){
            return stripe.charges.create({
            amount: ShoppingCartObject.totalPrice, // amount in cents, again
            currency: "usd",
            customer: customer.id
            });
        }), 
        Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(charge){
            ShoppingCartObject.charge.customer = charge.customer;
            submitOrder(ShoppingCartObject);
        })
    );
};

var submitOrder = function(ShoppingCartObject){
  check(ShoppingCartObject, Object);
  var data = _.omit(ShoppingCartObject, '_id');
  var setHash = { $set: data };
  ShoppingCarts.update({_id: ShoppingCartObject._id}, setHash);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of an approach that has worked for me. I basically create a function for each Stripe call that returns a Future.

```
// Server

var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

function createCustomer(token){
    var future = new Future;
    Stripe.customers.create({
      card: token.id,
      email: token.email
    }, function(error, result){
      if (error){
        future.return(error);
      } else {
        future.return(result);
      }
    });
    return future.wait();
  }

Meteor.methods({
  purchase: function(token){
    check(token: Object);
    try {
      var customer = createCustomer(token);
    } catch(error) {
      // error handle
    }
    // create charge, etc. repeating same pattern
  }
});
```

Comment: Still a relevant answer under Meteor 1.6.1, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I decided to work out everything using `Meteor.wrapAsync()`. The following code:

**EDIT**

After thinking about this, `wrapAsync()` seems to have some serious error-handling limitations, and especially for Stripe, where errors will be very common, my implementation below might be less-than-desireable.

Relevant discussion here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2774

User `faceyspacey` has this code to create a "better" `wrapAsync` that deals with errors more intuitively, although I haven't tried it yet.

```
Meteor.makeAsync = function(fn, context) {
  return function (/* arguments */) {
    var self = context || this;
    var newArgs = _.toArray(arguments);
    var callback;

    for (var i = newArgs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      var arg = newArgs[i];
      var type = typeof arg;
      if (type !== "undefined") {
        if (type === "function") {
          callback = arg;
        }
        break;
      }
    }

    if(!callback) {
      var fut = new Future();
            callback = function(error, data) {
               fut.return({error:  error, data: data});
            };

      ++i; 
    }

    newArgs[i] = Meteor.bindEnvironment(callback);
    var result = fn.apply(self, newArgs);
    return fut ? fut.wait() : result;
  };
};
```

**Original Code Below**

1. `ShoppingCartObject` has the details of the order and also the `cardToken` that is generated by `Stripe.js` when you feed it to the customer's credit card details.
2. A new customer is created with the `cardToken` saved, essentially saving their CC info for later use.
3. Lastly, a charge is created on the customer using their CC.

**code below**

```
var createStripeCustomerAsync = function(ShoppingCartObject, callback){

    var stripe = Stripe("sk_test_999999999999999999");

    stripe.customers.create({
        // this is the token generated on the client side from the CC info
      source: ShoppingCartObject.charge.cardToken,
      email: ShoppingCartObject.customer.email
    }, function(err, customer) {
      callback(err, customer);
    });

};

var createStripeCustomerSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(createStripeCustomerAsync);

var createStripeChargeAsync = function(customer, ShoppingCartObject, callback){

  var stripe = Stripe("sk_test_999999999999999999");

    stripe.charges.create({
      amount: ShoppingCartObject.totalPrice, // amount in cents, again
      currency: "usd",
      customer: customer.id
    }, function(error, charge){
        callback(error, charge);
    });

};

var createStripeChargeSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(createStripeChargeAsync);

var submitOrder = function(ShoppingCartObject){
    check(ShoppingCartObject, Object);

    var customer = createStripeCustomerSync(ShoppingCartObject);
    console.log("customer: ", customer);

    var charge = createStripeChargeSync(customer, ShoppingCartObject);
    console.log("charge: ", charge);

  var data = _.omit(ShoppingCartObject, '_id');
  var setHash = { $set: data };

  ShoppingCarts.update({_id: ShoppingCartObject._id}, setHash);
};
```