# correct way to use Stripe's stripe_account header from oauth with meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm trying to build a platform based on Meteor that uses Stripe Connect. I want to use the "preferred" authentication method from Stripe (Authentication via the Stripe-Account header, https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication) so that I can create plans and subscribe customers on behalf of my users. I cannot get it to work. I tried with a second params object, similar to the exemple in the documentation:

```
var stripeplancreate = Meteor.wrapAsync(Stripe.plans.create, Stripe.plans);
var plan = stripeplancreate({
  amount: prod.price,
  interval: prod.interv,
  name: prod.name,
  currency: prod.curr,
  id: prod.id+"-"+prod.price+"-"+prod.curr+"-"+prod.interv,
  metadata: { prodId: prod._id, orgId: org._id },
  statement_descriptor: prod.descr
},{stripe_account: org.stripe_user_id});
```

but I get "Exception while invoking method 'createStripeProduct' Error: Stripe: Unknown arguments ([object Object]). Did you mean to pass an options object? See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/wiki/Passing-Options." which does not seem to accurately reflect the issue but prompted me to try adding stripe_account in the params object itself:

```
var stripeplancreate = Meteor.wrapAsync(Stripe.plans.create, Stripe.plans);
var plan = stripeplancreate({
  amount: prod.price,
  (...)
  statement_descriptor: prod.descr,
  stripe_account: org.stripe_user_id
});
```

I then get the following error: "Exception while invoking method 'createStripeProduct' Error: Received unknown parameter: stripe_account"

Any ideas? Has anybody managed to have Stripe Connect stripe_account authentication work with Meteor, especially with Meteor.wrapAsync(...)?

Comment: I noticed in some other node code that they have 

    `var StripeAccount = require("../models/stripe_account");`

in addition to

    `var stripe = require("stripe")(config.stripe_secret_key);`

For exemple there: [link](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=stripe_account&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Is it another module that I may have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trying multiple things, for now, I just managed to get it working using the stripe-sync package instead of the "normal" one + wrapAsync.

```
try{
  var plan = Stripe.plans.create({
    amount: prod.price,
    ...
  },{stripe_account: org.stripe_user_id});
}catch(error){
  // ... process error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for `wrapAsync`, HOWEVER check out my answer here for possible issues with `wrapAsync` - [Wrapping Stripe create customer callbacks in Fibers in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035175/wrapping-stripe-create-customer-callbacks-in-fibers-in-meteor):

Here is also a great video on `wrapAsync`: https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-meteor-wrapasync

```
var createStripePlanAsync = function(shoppingCartObject, callback){

    stripe.plans.create({
      amount: shoppingCartObject.plan.totalPrice,
      interval: shoppingCartObject.plan.interval,
      name: shoppingCartObject.plan.planName,
      currency: "usd",
      id: shoppingCartObject.plan.sku //this ID needs to be unique!
    }, function(err, plan) {
      // asynchronously called
        callback(err, plan);
    });

};

var createStripePlanSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(createStripePlanAsync);

var myShoppingCart = {
    customerInfo: {
        name: "Igor Trout"
    },
    plan: {
        totalPrice: 5000,
        interval: "month",
        name: "Set Sail For Fail Plan",
        sku: "062015SSFF"
    }
};

// Creates the plan in your Stripe Account

createStripePlanSync(myShoppingCart);
```

Later when you subscribe a customer to a plan you just refer to the plan via the `id` that you gave the plan when you first created it.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers, i do have to handle exceptions a bit better. I did get it to work with wrapasync, no problem there, however i cannot seem to find the way to use the 'stripe_account' authentication so that i can create plans on behalf of my users and subscribe their clients to these plans. Any idea on this specific issue?

Comment: Ooof, I'm afraid this is out of the scope of my experience thus far. Three levels of users - you, your customers, and your customers' customers, right? You wanna be able to connect as your customers and then edit your customers' customer's information. You can always try the #stripe chatroom on IRC.

Comment: Yes, you got it right, three levels. I am collecting access rights through the oauth flow for standalone accounts: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts. That works as well, I'm just getting issues at the last step, getting the actual orders in on behalf of the connected account!